# Should Do Not Disturb be cancelling incoming calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, do-not-disturb

I was just wondering about DND. It was my understanding that DND just silenced notifications (calls, texts, alerts, etc) system wide.

I thought it just ensured that the screen does not light up and not audible notification is played, however it seems from my testing that when enabled DND actually cancels incoming calls, rather than just silencing the incoming call. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: what happens when you call twice in a row? DND is supposed to allow calls through that are immediately tried again. Does that still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS 7 description of Do Not Disturb states(accessible over Settings > Do Not Disturb)

> When Do Not Disturb is enabled calls and alerts that arrive while locked will be silenced, and a moon icon will appear in the status bar.

So DND should **not** cancel incoming calls.

This seems to be an ongoing problem/bug on the [official apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23363936#23363936).

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weird! Like i'm testing it right now and that's what it's doing... Can you check on your device ?

Comment: Just tested it, I cannot reproduce the problem. Running iOS 7.0.3 on an iPhone 5

Comment: So when you have DND enabled, calls still ring ?

Comment: As a caller, I get the busy tone. My iPhone is locked: The screen stays turned off, no ringing either.

Comment: Ahh so the call is effectively cancelled on you? - ie. it doesn't just make a ring noise? This is what I don't like, surely for the caller it should just ring out??

Comment: Well, afaik DND is designed to do exactly that. You can assign specific contacts to your favorites. They won't be blocked then. If you want to ring out the caller, I think you have to mute your phone and turn off vibration when muted(can be found under Settings > Sounds)

Answer (score 0):

When Do not disturb is on, the incoming calls won't be shown but only as a missed call.

Answer (score -1):

Report it at https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html as bug Report and Apple should work on it.